# how are the c language varibles are stored(in stack,list,tree?) where are they stored?(in ram /hdd)?

Tags: c, memory

i am a bit confused how the c variables stored in memory of a computer
   pls explain where they are stored and in what datastructure form they are stored?

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<conio.h>
 int main(void)
 {
  int r;
  int a,b,c;
  a=10;
  b=20;
   c=30;
 char e=3;
 int f[10]={1,2,3};

  printf("the value of pointers is\n %d\n %d\n %d\n %d\n %d\n %d\n",&a,&b,&c,&e,&f,&r);
  getch();
 }
```

Comment: Please read a good book on C programming. Enable all warnings and debug information with your compiler (with a GCC compiler, that means compile with `gcc -Wall -g`). Learn to use the debugger. Try to code standard compliant C code if possible (e.g. `<conio.h>` is not standard, and might be useless). Don't expect us to teach you programming in a few minutes.

Comment: can u explain me where they are stored i mean in ram/hdd/cpu registers where?

Comment: You should not care about where the C variables are stored, and that may change from one execution to the next, or from one system to another one.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch no i have a case to deal at device level which has very less memory(in kilobytes)..thats why i need where they are going to be stored..please note that the location alloted to  variables doesn't change..but may be the logical addresses may change.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_data_storage

Comment: Then, enable maximal optimization from your compiler, and inspect the generated assembly or machine code, and improve your C code or upgrade your system if that does not fit.

Comment: thankx every one for help ...thank u @Basile Starynkevitch            i am working with robotics..not computer:)

Comment: For me, a robot is a computer with additional sensors & actuators, so working with robots without understanding software seems very weird.

Comment: ok thnkx for ur help Basile Starynkevitch:)

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch ok i guess u r too far from basic robotics...they are never equivalent to computers...they cant run everything a computer runs...ok lets leave it here:P

Comment: The curiosity robot on Mars has a computer powerful enough for your code.

Comment: no i got many that can run most of my codes....xD.i even can run my code on u

Comment: computers also can't run everything other computers can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different storage classes in `c`, the ones in your example are stored in stack.

You probably should read up on `c` first.

Comment: @hacker .thnkx hacker....but where they are stored                   i mean in ram/hdd/cpu registers where?

Comment: @swetha: Why do you care about where the variables are stored? What should be important to you is the semantics and the behavior of your program. You might have it interpreted by an army of C standard compliant human slaves (that would be unethical and slow, but would still be C programming). Actually the variables could be stored in RAM, HDD, registers, whatever, it is implementation dependent and could vary from one run to the next, or from one system to the next.

Comment: An army of C standard compliant human slaves could be a valid implementation of the abstract virtual machine in the C language specification :).

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch no i have a case to deal at device level which has very less memory(in kilobytes)..thats why i need where they are going to be stored.

Comment: The compiler (if it a good one) will optimize sufficiently to put your C variables appropriately. You cannot predict where they are stored (if you really want, inspect the generated assembly code). It may be the case that your code requires more resource (RAM, disk...) than what is available on your system. This could be *undefined behavior* or a limitation of your C implementation.

Comment: Generally, if you really need to be aware of these particulars, asking on stackoverflow isn't sufficient…

Comment: @hacker yes i confirmed what u said...they are stored in ram(primary memory).only some variables which are specified to be stored in registers will do so.when some processing is needed the variables are copied to empty registers and processed.

Comment: The problem is that your question is about `c`, not about a particular implementation. And in reality compiler is free, for instance, to allocate no memory for local variables that are fine being registers and allocate memory for the variable you explicitly asked to be register, etc. That's why everyone is reluctant to answer your questions directly.

Comment: anyways thnkx for help @hacker

Answer (score 1):

In general (and I mean it, because for every sentence that I'll write here someone can find a counter example), ALL the C variables that you can define will be stored in memory (RAM).
Different types of variables can be saved in different types (*segments*) of memory.

Your compiled C program is located in the code segment.
Usual variables that you define in functions are defined on program's *stack* (also memory).
Variables that you allocate with malloc() et al. are located on *heap* (again, memory).
Nothing is stored on the disk, unless you write to some file.

Now, is what I said correct? Not exactly.
OS is deciding what is stored in RAM and what is stored on disk through *paging* mechanism.
Memory is managed in *pages*. Each page can be *swapped out* to the hard drive if the OS thinks that it should be, so all your variables can be in that page, which means that they will be stored on disk.
If this memory will be needed later on, OS will *swap in* this page back to the memory.

Again, this is in general.
Your OS can have paging disabled, in which case everything will always be in memory.
You can also map some portion of memory to present itself as disk drive, in which case everything that is written to this disk still stays in memory.

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

The exact details of where and how variables are stored is up to the implementation.  The language definition only specifies visibility and lifetime of variables, not the mechanism by which they are stored.

We'll look at one specific implementation - gcc 2.96 on Red Hat 7.2.

Here's a simple source file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int gvar = 1;            // file scope, static extent

int main(void)
{
  static int svar = 2;  // block scope, static keyword => static extent
  int avar = 3;         // block scope, auto extent

  do {
    int avar2 = 4;      // block scope, auto extent
    printf("gvar   = %d (%p)\nsvar   = %d (%p)\navar   = %d (%p)\navar2  = %d (%p)\n", 
    gvar, (void *) &gvar,
    svar, (void *) &svar,
    avar, (void *) &avar,
    avar2, (void *) &avar2);
  } while (0);

  return 0;
}
```

Variables declared with the keyword `static` or at file scope (outside of any function) have storage class `static`, meaning that the memory for those variables is allocated at program startup and held until the program exits.  Variables declared within a block and without the `static` keyword have storage class `auto`, meaning they only exist within that block<sup>1</sup>.  `avar2` cannot be referenced by name outside of the `do` loop, and it is not guaranteed to retain its value after the loop exits.

We compile the program with

```
gcc -o storage -g storage.c -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Werror -Wa,-aldh=storage.lst.redhat
```

The `-Wa,-alhd=...` will write a listing of the generated machine code to the specified file.  Since we add the `-g` debug flag, the original C source will be interleaved with the machine code.

Here's the output from the program:

```
gvar   = 1 (0x80495b0)
svar   = 2 (0x80495b4)
avar   = 3 (0xbfffe4e4)
avar2  = 4 (0xbfffe4e0)
```

Clearly, on this implementation, variables with static extent like `gvar` and `avar` are stored somewhere quite differently from variables with auto extent like `avar` and `x`.

Here's the listing of the generated assembly code (minus some page breaks):

```
   1                    .file   "storage.c"
   2                    .version    "01.01"
   5                .text
   6                .Ltext0:
 165                .globl gvar
 166                .data
 168                    .align 4
 171                gvar:
 172 0000 01000000      .long   1
 173                    .align 4
 176                svar.0:
 177 0004 02000000      .long   2
 178                        .section    .rodata
 179                    .align 32
 180                .LC0:
 181 0000 67766172      .string "gvar   = %d (%p)\nsvar   = %d (%p)\nvar   = %d (%p)\navar2  = %d (%p)\n"
 181      2020203D 
 181      20256420 
 181      28257029 
 181      0A737661 
 182 0044 00000000  .text
 182      00000000 
 182      00000000 
 182      00000000 
 182      00000000 
 183                    .align 4
 185                .globl main
 187                main:
   1:storage.c     **** #include 
   2:storage.c     **** 
   3:storage.c     **** int gvar = 1;
   4:storage.c     **** 
   5:storage.c     **** int main(void)
   6:storage.c     **** {
 189                .LM1:
 190                .LBB2:
 191 0000 55            pushl   %ebp
 192 0001 89E5          movl    %esp, %ebp
 193 0003 83EC08        subl    $8, %esp
   7:storage.c     ****   static int svar = 2;
   8:storage.c     ****   int avar = 3;
 195                .LM2:
 196 0006 C745FC03      movl    $3, -4(%ebp)
 196      000000
   9:storage.c     **** 
  10:storage.c     ****   do {
  11:storage.c     ****     int avar2 = 4;
 198                .LM3:
 199                .LBB3:
 200 000d C745F804      movl    $4, -8(%ebp)
 200      000000
  12:storage.c     ****     printf("gvar   = %d (%p)\nsvar   = %d (%p)\nvar   = %d (%p)\navar2  = %d (%p)\n", 
 202                .LM4:
 203 0014 83EC0C        subl    $12, %esp
 204 0017 8D45F8        leal    -8(%ebp), %eax
 205 001a 50            pushl   %eax
 206 001b FF75F8        pushl   -8(%ebp)
 207 001e 8D45FC        leal    -4(%ebp), %eax
 208 0021 50            pushl   %eax
 209 0022 FF75FC        pushl   -4(%ebp)
 210 0025 68040000      pushl   $svar.0
 210      00
 211 002a FF350400      pushl   svar.0
 211      0000
 212 0030 68000000      pushl   $gvar
 212      00
 213 0035 FF350000      pushl   gvar
 213      0000
 214 003b 68000000      pushl   $.LC0
 214      00
 215 0040 E8FCFFFF      call    printf
 215      FF
 216 0045 83C430        addl    $48, %esp
  13:storage.c     ****     gvar, (void *) &gvar,
  14:storage.c     ****     svar, (void *) &svar,
  15:storage.c     ****     avar, (void *) &avar,
  16:storage.c     ****     avar2, (void *) &avar2);
  17:storage.c     ****   } while (0);
 218                .LM5:
 219                .LBE3:
  18:storage.c     **** 
  19:storage.c     ****   return 0;
 221                .LM6:
 222 0048 B8000000      movl    $0, %eax
 222      00
  20:storage.c     **** }
 224                .LM7:
 225                .LBE2:
 226 004d C9            leave
 227 004e C3            ret
 228                .Lfe1:
 237                .Lscope0:
 239                    .text
 241                .Letext:
 242 004f 90            .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 2.96 20000731 (Red Hat Linux 7.2 2.96-112.7.2)"
```

It's a lot to slog through, but it tells us why we get such differences in memory addresses.

The lines

```
   5                .text
   6                .Ltext0:
 165                .globl gvar
 166                .data
 168                    .align 4
 171                gvar:
 172 0000 01000000      .long   1
 173                    .align 4
 176                svar.0:
 177 0004 02000000      .long   2
```

tell us that the memory for `gvar` and `svar` is located in the `.text` section of the program image, which is where the program code resides.

In comparison the lines

```
 195                .LM2:
 196 0006 C745FC03      movl    $3, -4(%ebp)
 196      000000
...
 198                .LM3:
 199                .LBB3:
 200 000d C745F804      movl    $4, -8(%ebp)
 200      000000
```

tell us that the memory for `avar` and `avar2` is located relative to the current frame pointer (stored in `%ebp`); `avar` is stored 4 bytes offset from the frame pointer, while `avar2` is stored 8 bytes offset from the frame pointer.

Again, this is how *one version of one compiler on one operating system* does it; different compilers on different operating systems may use a different structure (although this approach is *very* common).

If you're really itching to know the exact details, you'll want to learn more about your architecture (x86 vs. Power vs. MIPS vs...), and you'll want to do some assembly programming.

---

<sup>1.  Note that this doesn't necessarily mean that memory will be allocated and deallocated every time the block is entered and exited; normally, the same memory locations will be reused, but you cannot guarantee that they'll have the same value they did when the block was exited.</sup>